# Is it posible to have an outliers greater than the first quartile(Q1)?

Tags: statistics

Below is the set of values that I want to find outliers.

```
24, 102, 110, 118, 172, 184, 239, 284, 325, 363, 381, 465
```

- Q1 Percentile: 114
- Q2 Percentile: 211.5
- Q3 Percentile: 344
- Interquartile Range(IQR): 230

So my calculation for outliers are below:

Q3 + 1.5(IQR) = 689 - there is no outliers(this is fine).

Q1 - 1.5(IQR) = 231  - Any number less than 231 are outliers(from what I learned).

My question is, **Is it possible to have outliers greater than first quartile?**

*Also I checked outliers using [online calculator](http://www.miniwebtool.com/outlier-calculator/), it is display: no outliers.*

Comment: I think this depend on your definition of outlier, for your purposes

Comment: So, how you define outliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Q_1=114$$

$$Q_1 - 1.5IQR \leq Q_1$$ since $IQR \geq 0$, hence the number $231$ must be wrong.